# Is it possible to break flash card programmatically?

Tags: filesystems, flash-memory

I think I broke my flash card programmatically while was playing with automount configuration. Now I can't mount my card anuwhere.

Was this possible? And if it was, then how to ensure and fix?

Comment: AFAIK no flash memory can handle unlimited write cycles. To break a flash card programatically one needs just an endless loop that writes to the card. The card will fail eventually. This answers the title but I don't think it's an answer you want; therefore just a comment.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I disagree. Depending on the card it has internal wear leveling preventing a failure like described (good SDcards do have that). And any flash device I know of has at least spare blocks: On write failures blocks are transparently exchanged by spare blocks. Without this mechanism you could not produce reliable flash storage at all using modern MLC flash. Even if a failure doesn't get detected and you ruin a crucial point of your file system, you can at least reformat the storage.

Comment: @Dims A hundred reasons for not being able to mount. To narrow the problem: What kind of flash card attached to which interface? For example, an SDcard can be connected to the MMC bus of the CPU/MCU or to a USB adapter. If you have any response in `dmesg` on inserting the card, please add it to your question. Finally, if the card doesn't even get detected anymore, my best guess is an electromechanical issue: Especially cheap microSD cards can easily get damaged on taking it out and in again too often (which you probably did on automount playing).

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether you just can't mount because the filesystem somehow got broken, or whether you can't talk to the storage device anymore at all (i.e. does it appear in `lsblk` in a correct size?).

If you can't talk to it anymore:

As Kamil [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/744218/is-it-possible-to-break-flash-card-programmatically#comment1415129_744218), write fatigue is a very reliable means of breaking flash media. (The physicality of it is really that the small gate capacitors that make up the storage wear out, and you have to adjust your readout decision voltage thresholds until you can't make a reliable decision on what was stored.)

Now, assuming that's not what happened here:

Any commercial flash card (SD cards, compact flash, xD, …) since the demise of SmartMedia is bulk flash storage + an ASIC that includes a microcontroller to interface with both that storage and the interface to your camera, card reader, laptop, smart phone…

Microcontrollers run software (firmware).

Software has bugs.

You might have just hit a rare bug, by trying something occassionally failing very often (connecting/disconnecting to work with your automount, a couple hundred times in quick succession?).

Whether or not that is recoverable: I don't know, you'd have to ask the firmware vendor. (which probably means, for all practical purposes of your case, no.)